# Can I add a virtual IP address to a network adapter remotely?

Tags: windows-server-2003, networking, ip, remote-access

My organization is trying to reduce our dependency on remote desktop connections to administer servers, with a mind to disable RDP for all but the most privileged users.

Is there a way to configure network adapters via a remote administration tool?

Comment: Why avoid the best single tool for administration on Windows? RDP is the standard method for administrating Windows servers, there's a strong permissions model to facilitate this. Taking SSH away from the Linux admins, too?

Comment: They do all sorts of things in the name of "security". I'm sure they'll turn off the boxes one day and go "Yes! Nobody can access now!" All I can do is try and find solutions around their problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep. The **netsh** command can be used with the -r -u and -p switches (remote computer, username, password respectively) to remotely configure windows networking.

Comment: Could I press you for an example? The netsh documentation and built-in help is a little unclear for me.

Comment: >netsh -r "my_server.domain.com" -u "domain.com\my_account" -p "my_password" interface ipv4 show